# Why do genetic testing companies (FTDNA,AncestryDNA,23andme) express DNA shared in centimorgans (cM) instead of in number of base pairs or in percent?

Tags: human-genetics, dna-sequencing, human-genome, recombination, genetic-linkage

Expressing DNA shared in number of base pairs or in percent of total genome would be so much simpler and easier to understand for the customers.

.

[image: FTDNA uses centimorgans (cM)]

Comment: What kind of data / reports are you referring to? Also not that these comapies do **not** perform DNA sequencing, they do DNAchip based SNP characterisation; therefore any actual basepair positions they could give would come from a refernece genome, which has to have a specific version and is not easy to use/understand for customers.

Comment: @Nicolai You could probably make an answer out of your comment.